# Font Size increase in angular with [ngClass]="fontSize"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have header.component and if i click Small, medium, large button font size resize globally(all application components).
here is my link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrmgdt

Attached my UI screenshot for your ref[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxTqi.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you be more specific on your problem. I see no question in your description

Comment: How to put font size increase button in angular?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrmgdt i have used ng class methord but tht is working only for header component i need to use font size increasing action for all application components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a `DocumentService` that will set the `font-size` attribute of the documents `<html>` element (see stackblitz below).  You could then size your elements in `rem` to scale based on the `<html>` elements font-size.

#### document.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Optional, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class DocumentService {

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

  setCss(element, attribute, value) {
    this.document.querySelector(element).style[attribute] = value;
  }

}
```

#### header.component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() sidenav: MatSidenav;

  constructor(private documentService: DocumentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggle(size) {
    this.documentService.setCss('body', 'font-size', size);
  }
}
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mg9k7b

Comment: ***@Jason White Thanks for your solution*** my issue got fixed.